# Alternative to args.join(" ")?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to create a poll on discord using discord.js, and while I've mostly got it working there is one thing that I cannot figure out.

Here is my code:

```
emojiArray = [
  ":number_one:530589007504080917",
  ":number_two:530588366719287306",
  ":number_three:530589050311016458",
  ":number_four:530589092329816075",
  ":number_five:530589126643286056",
  ":number_six:530589166946222090",
  ":number_seven:530589218796208129",
  ":number_eight:530589262471626762",
  ":number_nine:530589298504892417"
];
let reactionNumber = args[0];
embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
  .setColor(0xffffff)
  .setFooter("note: any reactions that are not part of the poll will be removed")
  .setDescription(args.join(" "))
  .setTitle(`Poll created by ${message.author.username}`);
message.channel.send(embed).then(async function(message) {
  for (x = 0; x < reactionNumber; x++) {
    await message.react(emojiArray[x]);
  }
  reactionNumber.replace(args[0], '');
}).catch(function() {
  message.channel.sendMessage(err);
});
message.delete({
  timeout: 1000
});
```

The user would input the command: `[prefix]poll [number of reactions] [description]`
It would look like this: `p!poll 9 test`

At the moment this is the result:

[image: Picture of the result of the code]

You'll notice that the "9" in the command is also in the description, and I'm not able to figure out how to fix that.

The only thing I tried was a:

```
reactionNumber.replace(args[0],'');
```

Which I hoped would remove the "9" or whatever was inputted after it wasn't needed anymore. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Why not just `.setDescription(args[1])`?

Comment: That was what I used before, but it would only allow a one word description. For example when I used the command **p!poll 9 this is a test** the description would only come up as "test". Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing `reactionNumber` after `setDescription` won't do anything; instead, change this line with the one below:

```
.setDescription(args.join(" ")) // WRONG ✗
.setDescription(args.splice(1).join(" ")) // RIGHT ✓
```

Comment: args[1] only allows me to have a 1 word description. I had tried this before, but when I put in a description like: "this is a test". It would only return "this". Any thoughts?

Comment: ok just edit my answer @Alden Clint ,  so you basically just want to remove the first value of args